# Looking for the opposite of flexglobals.toplevelapplication

Tags: custom-component, textinput, global, refer

If I want to refer to a textInput (for example) in the top level application from a custom component. Than I can use FlexGlobals.toplevelapplication but how do I refer to a textInput in a custom component from the top level application. So I need the opposite from FlexGlobals.toplevelapplication.